# Is there a way to hide applications from other desktops/workspaces in the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

I don't want to see applications that are opened on my other desktops (workspaces) in my Unity launcher (or sidebar, whatever it is called). I find it annoying and would prefer if Unity just dealt with one desktop/workspace at a time.

Is there a way to do this? I have a feeling the answer will be no, but I'm asking anyway... maybe it will be implemented in future versions.

Comment: I think by "desktops" you mean "workspaces".

Comment: Yes, this was referred to as a desktop before Unity. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a rather lengthy bug-report on just this matter on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/683170).

Even Mark Shuttleworth got involved with this one.  However no conclusions or proposals for implementation yet.

Comment: atleast now it is possible, you can find answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1231751/935982