# How to make unity hide applications from the launcher if they're running on other desktops/workspaces?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I would like to be able to hide applications running in other workspaces, under Unity.

For example, chrome is open in workspace 1, and when I go to another workspace, it should be hidden from the launcher.  Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/54778/18612

Comment: Try this **How To Switch Between Different Lists of Pinned Apps on the Unity Launcher** http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/switch-profiles-unity-launcher-pinned-apps

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible. The launcher shows all running apps and doesn't provide a way to hide some.