# Show only the active workspace on the launcher

Tags: 12.04, launcher, workspaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to hide applications from other desktops/workspaces in the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54778/is-there-a-way-to-hide-applications-from-other-desktops-workspaces-in-the-unity)

Is there a way in 12.04 to show only icons that are active on the current workspace

Comment: Look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/54778/