# How to trigger a script on entering/exiting a workspace?

Tags: scripts, launcher, workspaces

This is regarding ubuntu 15.10. I have enabled workspaces, and would like unity launcher sidebar to show open application icon only if it was opened in the current workspace.
To do so, I have already followed the answer at
[Setting to only show applications of current workspace in launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305962/setting-to-only-show-applications-of-current-workspace-in-launcher).
It worked on 15.10, and I have assigned a shortcut key.
However the answer shows how to assign a keyboard shortcut to trigger the script. I would like that python script to automatically execute when switching in and out of a workspace.
The answer could specify different triggers for entering / exiting the workspace.

Comment: I actually got it working in those days, but only posted the "shortcut" version because of a relatively high processor load (adding > 3%). A fresh look at it might make it work at "lower costs" now. I will if I find the time in the next few days.

Comment: I don't think users care about 3% Processor load. Most of the users use ubuntu as an OS for desktop, where you don't need to care about CPU usage as much as for servers. So anyways with 4 cores,  3% / 400 % won't be too much.

Comment: Hi Shivam. I have an answer to *this* question. However: while the *shortcut* version works fine on the linked script, in combination with what I now produced, the script starts misbehaving, hiding windows on the current viewport occasionally. This is most likely the result of a timing issue, causing the script to be out of phase somehow.  Probably I will rewrite the linked script, since the question is (still) an interesting one.