# Ubuntu 18 - launcher to only show applications in current workspace

Tags: launcher, workspaces, dock

I'm trying to seperate workspaces so that the dock/launcher will only show applications in its current workspace/virtual desktop.

I tried several suggestions online but they didn't work.

When I did:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces true
```

Nothing happened. It still would show all applications in all workstations.

I also tried following the solution in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305962/setting-to-only-show-applications-of-current-workspace-in-launcher) but I got this error when trying to open `dconf-editor`:

```
root@jeff-ws:~# dconf-editor 
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(dconf-editor:15565): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:54:05.990: cannot open display: :0
```

Does anyone happen to know how to get it working? Running on `18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)`

Huge thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Running `dconf-editor` as root allowed me to follow the steps in the thread I provided. This solved the issue.